# How do I get the value of an asp:label in an Advertisement string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may sound like a strange one, but it is the only way I can do what I need to do, so here it goes:

I have:

```
 <asp:Label ID="LabelStoreNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

on an .aspx page.  I want to use the value of:
`LabelStoreNumber.Text`  later in the asp page in an advertisement file 
     string.  The advertisement line looks like this:

```
<asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server"  Height="150" Width ="200" 
AdvertisementFile="<value of LabelStorNumber.Text>/PIC_List/PicList.xml"/>
```

The goal is that anyone visting this page will automatically be directed to their store numbers PicList.xml directory.

I have tried without success:

```
<asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator2" runat="server"  Height="150" Width ="200" 
AdvertisementFile="document.getElementById('<%=LabelStoreNumber.ClientID%>')
.innerText;/Alets/PIC_List/PicList1.xml"/>
```

My big problem is I cannot see what actually is being returned so I am not sure if I am close or not.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Try to inspect the element to find out what your Javascript code is returning . Press F12 in Chrome or IE. Find your AD rotator markup in the DOM Explorer of Inspect element window

Comment: Vidiya, thanks for the suggestion. I am only seeing DOM breakpoints and it doesn't show anything...where is the DOM Explorer

Comment: In chrome's Inspect element, you can see it under "Elements" . In IE, it is under "DOM Explorer". You can find the whole HTML content that has been loaded. Find your Ad Rotator control and you will be able to see what has been rendered there

Comment: That is where I was looking but it just says 'The AdRotator AdRotator2 could not find the AdvertisementFile or the file is invalid.' No code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a property of the server-side AdRotator control using client-side code. Instead you should set the `AdvertisementFile` property on the server-side, in the page's code behind file. E.g. that would look something like this (in `Page_Load()` for example):

```
AdRotator2.AdvertisementFile = LabelStoreNumber.Text + "/PIC_List/PicList.xml";
```

Comment: That makes sense but not sure of how to incorporate into the page:<asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server"  Height="150" Width ="200" AdvertisementFile=

Comment: Got it! Thanks M4M! That was easier than I thought!